# Julia: `Vector{Any}` vs. `[]`

Tags: types, julia, typeerror

In a function, I created a vector

```
a = Vector{Vector{Int}}
```

This is, a vector of vectors with the inner vectors containing `Int` types. I was receiving type errors when trying to `push!` elements into `a`, even though the elements I was trying to push were effectively of type `Vector{Int}`.

Upon further investigation, I found the following. Defining `a` as `Vector{Any}` gives a `DataType`.

```
a = Vector{Any}
typeof(a)

> DataType
```

When attempting to push an element into this vector, I get an error:

```
push!(a, x)

> MethodError: no method matching push!(::Type{Vector{Any}}, ::Vector{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at abstractarray.jl:3059
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at abstractarray.jl:3060
  push!(::DataStructures.Deque{T}, ::Any) where T at ~/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0/src/deque.jl:217
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[54]:1
```

where `x` is a `Vector{Int64}` type variable.

However, defining `a` as `a=[]` gives

```
a = []
typeof(a)

> Vector{Any} (alias for Array{Any, 1})
```

and pushing works correctly:

```
push!(a, x)

> 1-element Vector{Any}:
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  …  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This arouse many questions. Firstly, why does specifying the type of `a` with `a = Vector{T}` result in an object of type `DataType`? Why does the `push` function fail on such objects?

More importantly, if `a = Vector{T}` does not give an object of type `Vector{T}` but of type `DataType`, how do I define a vector with a restricted type, allowing for the `push` function to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, why does specifying the type of a with a = Vector{T} result in an object of type DataType?

Because that's what `Vector{T}` is - it is the same as `Float64`, or `String`, just a datatype, not an *instance* of that type.

> Why does the push function fail on such objects?

That's hopefully clear from the above - it doesn't really make sense to push something into a type (rather than an instance of that type).

> More importantly, if a = Vector{T} does not give an object of type Vector{T} but of type DataType, how do I define a vector with a restricted type, allowing for the push function to work?

As explained in other answers, you need to instantiate a type by calling its constructor, `T()`. In this case it would be `Vector{Any}()`, although for arrays it is more common to use the `T[]` syntax to create a typed array, in your case that would be `Any[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Vector{Any}` is the DataType and, to create a vector, you'll need to call the constructor method. So, if you call `a = Vector{Any}()`, then you'll get the same result as `a = []`.

See here for more info: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/.